# magento store working very slow after added categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Fresh installation of `Magento 1.9.1` working very slow after added many categories and subcategories only.

No any customization or third party extension has been installed.

There are 10 main categories and more than 100 subcategories.

I think there is no such limitation over number of categories into Magento.

I was using shared hosting. Later I have migrated it over **VPS**.
**(ssd , ram 4gb , cpu 4 core)** but still problem is same.

can you please help me?

Comment: Have you enabled flat catalog and flat category, and then re-indexed?

Comment: thanks lot for your answer , yes i tested it and get good answer , but another problem that i have it is that filtrable attributes is 347! and magento don't accept this for reindex. can i get your email or skype for describe more my mean ?

Comment: Best to create a new question in this forum. The question and answer may help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original conment placed as answer as it seemed to fix the answered question:

Have you enabled flat catalog and flat category, and then re-indexed